# Problem Import Flutter Project to Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle

I tried to import flutter project from my pc to the android studio and got this error.
I already read the link that they give to me but I still don't understand. A little help please, or how do I import flutter project correctly?

The error

[image: img]

Comment: Does it happen for sample counter app?

Answer (score 1):

The project is not Gradle based can be because bulid.gradle  and settings.gradle are not in the IDE project directory,

Try this

> Open that other folder as an Android Studio Project and let it download other dependencies and file or you can create new flutter project and check the file generated with yours and try to add the file not in your own from the new flutter project you created.

This will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

from which version/tool you imported the project?. This is normally happed because of gradle-wrapper issues. Please check the link.
https://quick-adviser.com/how-can-we-solve-project-is-not-a-gradle-based-project/

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this by File -> Repair IDE